Curl request to haproxy node returning resulting in SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN
I am trying to send a large multipart file to my server through haproxy. However, the request fails with SD-- in the log and the curl verbose output produces the following (command is being run on the haproxy node):
# curl --location 'https://localhost/myserver/api/fileUpload' --form 'file=@"myFile.zip"' --form "manifest=@manifest.json;type=application/json" -kv
> POST /myserver/api/fileUpload HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1131051568
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------7a8f18fbe3daeabf
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):
* OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, errno 32
* Closing connection 0

The issue does not appear with smaller files which leads me to believe that it's related to the 100 Continue thing.
